# Cannot connect to dockerized Cassandra

Tags: spring, docker, cassandra, jhipster

Code is throwing the following exception:

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is 

 com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException:
 All host(s) tried for query failed
 (
   tried:

   localhost/127.0.0.1:9042
   (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [localhost/127.0.0.1:9042]
    Cannot connect),

   localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9042
   (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9042]
    Cannot connect)
 )
```

I'm using [JHipster example found at GitHub](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app-cassandra). Running `mvnw clean test` does not return any failure.

Ports 9042 and 9160 are already opened in the firewall.

Dependencies are cassandra-driver-extras, cassandra-driver-mapping and spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra.

Comment: Did you start cassandra with docker-compose?  It's not embedded, you have to launch it separately

Comment: I think you're using the wrong ip. Try this: docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' container_name_or_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the important section of application-dev.yml:

```
spring:
    data:
        cassandra:
            contactPoints: localhost
            protocolVersion: V4
            compression: LZ4
            keyspaceName: demo_ks
            entityPackage: com.demo.domain
            port: 9042
```

Had to use a docker-compose file which starts container `cassandra:3.11.3`, ports 9042, 9160, 7199, 7000, 7001 and volume `cassandra_data:/data`. I'll later put it all on some GitHub repository and edit this answer with the complete code.

My `CassandraConfiguration` class has beans returning `CassandraCustomConversions`, `ClusterBuilderCustomizer` and `Session`, also autowired `Cluster` and `MetricRegistry`.

Important sections of `pom.xml`:

```
<properties>
    <spring-boot.version>2.0.5.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.cassandraunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-unit-spring</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-extras</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Have you had a chance to put your solution on Github? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: @QuintenScheppermans I don't know if I have this code anymore, since I was using a corporate computer, but I'll check it out later.